# Edit objects in a page with Xwiki

Tags: velocity, xwiki

I'm trying to edit a object in a wiki page

I created a class with name = "Test.Message" and a single string attribute named "text"

I put this code in a page

```
{{velocity}}

{{html clean="false" wiki="true"}}
#set($mobj=$doc.getObject("Tests.Message",true))
$mobj.display("text",$context.action)<p/>
{{/html}}  

{{/velocity}}
```

It show the form but when I save the page the object is not saved/updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you bind the object to the page?